# Solving a PDE with Feynman-Kac Formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I'm trying to solve this PDE using Feynman-Kac formula
[image]

Now i follow the regular steps

[image]

Here is where I don't know how to proceed. How do I calculate this expectation?

Comment: Well, I would say that $F(t,x) = \mathsf E_{(t,x)}[X^2_T]$ is the starting point. You've a found a correct SDE:
$$
  \mathrm dX_t = \mu\mathrm dt + \sigma X_t \mathrm dB_t.
$$
Now, to compute expectation try to derive ODEs for first and second moments.

Comment: @Ilya Convert to integral equation and then take expectation?

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in the comment, just use the SDE that you derived to obtain ODEs for the moments of $X_T$. That is, let $m(t) = \mathsf EX_t$, then $\mathrm dm_t = \mu\mathrm dt$. A similar equation you can derive for $v(t) = X^2_t$ using Ito's lemma. That's pretty much it.

**Edit:** you will get the following SDE
$$
  \mathrm dX^2_t = (2\mu X_t +\sigma^2 X_t^2)\mathrm dt + 2 \sigma X^2_t\mathrm dB_t
$$
so that
$$
  d v(t) = (2\mu m(t) + \sigma^2 v(t) )\mathrm dt
$$
and if you've found $m(t)$ as I suggested above, you just need to solve this simple ODE for $v$. Since it is non-homogeneous, you can e.g. use Lagrange method of variating the constant.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I'm still not sure what to do. Should try to calculate the SDE for Z=X^2 and then somehow reach the answer?

Comment: @Carl: exactly.

Comment: Because I then have this equation:
first the SDE:  
dZ=2Xdx+sigma^2*X^2dt = (sigma^2*X+2*mu)Xds+2X^2*sigma dB 
I take the integral and expectation and but I don't know how to proceed. I get both Z and X in the equation.  
Sorry If the calcualtion are hard to see but I don't now how to format the text better