# An unzipping problem

Tags: integration, analysis, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, special-relativity

Imagine a continuous one-dimensional line, which is duplicated exactly once. Duplication starts at random spacetime points. Once a point is duplicated, it starts a double duplication wave moving in either direction at constant speed $v$ (similar to a bi-directional zipper), as the following animation suggests

[image]

$I(x,t)$ is defined as the probability the position $x$, if not already duplicated at time $t$, initiates a double wave at time $t$.

Consider now a large number of lines and define $s(x,t)$ as the fraction of lines where position $x$ has not yet been duplicated ($I(x,t)$ is the same across all lines). From this definition, we may extract the probability distribution of duplication timing.

First, note that a position $x$ is not duplicated at time $t$ iff its duplication timing $t_D(x)$ is greater than $t$. Therefore the probability distribution $P(x,t)$ of the duplication timing at position $x$ is given by
$$
P(x,t)=-\partial_t s(x,t)
$$
as $s(x,t)=\text{Prob}(t_D(x)\geq t)$.

**Question:** In my modelling approach, I define the term $f(x)$, which is the rate of initiation at position $x$, constant in time, which should be related to $I(x,t)$ in some form. I am interested in determining the expected time of duplication at a given position $x$, defined as $\langle t_D(x)\rangle$ and inverting the problem: is it possible to write the initiation rate $f(x)$ in terms of $\langle t_D(x)\rangle$? $\langle t_D(x)\rangle$ has also been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622582/expected-timing-of-an-activation-process), from a different perspective.

**My attempt:** For infinite and continuous lines, this problem has been studied in the context of [nucleation and replication](https://www.embopress.org/doi/epdf/10.1038/msb.2010.61). In particular, it was shown that, using light-cone coordinates,
$$
s(x,t)=e^{-\int_{V_X[v]}dYI(Y)}
$$
where $V_X[v]$ is the past light cone of the spacetime point $X=(x,t)$. This equation has the following elegant inverse, using the D'Alembert operator $\square=\frac{1}{v^2}\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2$,
$$
I(x,t)=-\frac{v}{2}\square \log s(x,t)
$$
On the other hand, given the probabilistic description provided before, we also have
$$
\langle t_D(x)\rangle=\int_0^\infty tP(x,t)\,dt=-\int_0^\infty t\partial_ts(x,t)\,dt
$$
However, from here, it is not clear how to rewrite this so that I have the rate $f(x)$ as a function of $\langle t_D(x)\rangle$. In particular, how are $I(x,t)$ and $f(x)$ related? The general steps could potentially be:

1. Write $s(x,t)$ in terms of $\langle t_D(x)\rangle$.
2. Use D'Alembert formula to write $I(x,t)$ in terms of $\langle t_D(x)\rangle$.
3. Write $f(x)$ in terms of $I(x,t)$.
4. What happens in the discrete space case, where duplication only starts at specific points $\{x_i\}$ (say integers in the real line, for simplicity)? For instance, what happens when $I(x,t)\equiv\sum_{y\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(x-y)I(x,t)$?

Any ideas?

**Other general ideas:**

- The [inverse Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Inverse_Laplace_transform) could prove useful to invert the previous equation, but [not too sure how](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4855690/generalizing-a-laplace-transform). Similarly, the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) could hold some useful information.
- Initiation is a Poisson process where only the first event matters (there is no re-duplication), therefore can conditionality be relaxed and is there a direct relation between initiation rate $f(x)$ and probability $I(x,t)$ over time? In particular, due to the constant speed, waves do not overlap and the expected time should be the same nonetheless.
- I am generally hoping for an elegant solution, but if not possible, where is the issue?

Comment: Are you interested by answer ? if not I shall delete.

Answer (score 3):

I hope that I understood your modelling approach and terminology correctly. I will show how to get from $f(x)$ to $\mathbb{E}t_D(x)$ by analizing a general case first. I think going in the opposite direction is much harder because it involves "inverting a kernel".

**Solution for Poisson point process**

If we can assume that instances of "starts of duplication" (let's call them "pops") conform to Poisson point process, that is:

- numbers of pops in disjoint regions of spacetime are independent random variables,
- number of pops in a region of spacetime $A \subset \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+ $ follows Poisson distribution with a parameter $\mu(A)$ where $\mu$ is some measure on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+$,
- $\mu(A)$ is finite for compact $A$ (technical assumption),

then we can arrive to a somewhat elegant solution.

Let $A_{x,t}$ denote the region in which the pop would need to occur in order to point $x$ get duplicated by the time $t$. In one dimensional case it is a triangle with vertices at: $$(x,t), (x-vt, 0), (x+vt, 0).$$

Let $N(A)$ be the (random) number of pops in region $A$, then
$$t_D(x) > t \iff N(A_{x,t}) = 0$$

and
$$\mathbb{P}(t_D(x) > t) = \mathbb{P}(N(A_{x,t}) = 0) = e^{-\mu(A_{x,t})}.$$

Using $\mathbb{E}X = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>t)dt$, we get

$$\mathbb{E}t_D(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu(A_{x,t})} dt.$$

**Solution for rate of initiation constant in time**

For constant rate of initiation $f(x)$ we have $\mu(dxdt) = f(x)dxdt$. We can then calculate

$$\mu(A_{x,t})
= \int_{x-vt}^{x+vt}f(y)(t-|x-y|/v)dy
$$

and plug that into the formula for $\mathbb{E}t_D(x)$.

For constant $f(x)=f$ we get $\mu(A_{x,t}) = f vt^2$ and

$$
\mathbb{E}t_D(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-fvt^2} dt = \frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{fv}}
$$

Comment: This is an interesting approach. However, I am still struggling to understand something. For example, if we take a constant initiation rate (in space-time), say $f(x)=f$, I would expect to get, in light-cone coordinates, $s(x,t)=1-e^{-\int_0^t \int_{x-vt}^{x+vt}f\,dy\,dt}=1-e^{-f vt^2}  $ and thus $\mathbb{E}t_D(x)=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{fv}}$, where naturally the $x$ dependence is non-existent here. However, I do not seem to get that from your deduction. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by an exponential distribution "along dt"? If space is discrete, the time it takes for a site to pop [follows an exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4626342/487230), but I don't see the analogy in the continuous case. Interestingly, the $\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{fv}}$ estimate [also arises](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4636332/487230) in the discrete case, but the goal is to unify this framework.

Comment: One last comment. I might be influenced by the discrete case, and where each discrete site pops with a rate $f(x)$, and some terminology might be wrong, but I wonder whether it is relatively possible to shift between continuous and discrete settings. [In this paper](https://www.embopress.org/doi/epdf/10.1038/msb.2010.61) (page 10, eq 5), they consider discrete "popping" by using delta functions, but it is not clear to me whether the explicit calculation of $\mathbb{E}t_d$ can be achieved. A bit of an overkill, but hopefully this sheds some light on the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Oh, you are right! It is the time of the first pop that is "exponential along dt" when the intensity is constant, as it should be. It that case $\mu(dxdt) = f(x)dxdt$ and you calculation checks out :) I will edit the answer to fix this

Comment: The reasoning easily generalizes to discrete or even mixed settings and will work with all kinds of measures $\mu$. Let's say you want to model "pops" only occurring at integer points (with intensities $f_n$), you would then get $\mu(A_{x,t}) = \sum_n f_n \max(t-|x-n|/v, 0)$

Comment: Thanks! I might have overused the variable $t$, but you get it. I think I understand where the "deeper" problem might lie. The data I have is on the discrete position-dependent mean time of duplication ($\mathbb{E}t_D(x_i)$). However, the d'Alembert formula is written in terms of $s(x,t)$. While $\mathbb{E}t_D(x_i)=-\int_0^\infty t \partial_ts(x,t)\,dt$, I am not sure I can invert this and apply the fitting to get $I(x,t)$ in terms of  $\mathbb{E}t_D(x_i)$. If $I(x,t)=f$, it's easy to invert. Perhaps something with Laplace transforms or Lambert W functions could tell more. Is this issue clear?

Comment: Also, I think the measure in the discrete case would be written in terms of Dirac delta functions, right? Are you able to write that specifically? [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4855061/how-to-simplify-int-0t-int-x-sxs-sum-i-deltay-ifi-s-dyds).

Comment: You could write $\mu(dxdt) = (\sum_{n}f_n\delta(dx-n))dt$

Comment: If you're after analytical solution, one thing that might be helpful in solving the PDE is to apply Fourier transform wrt space dimension.

If it's rather the case of fitting $f(x)$ to experimental data I would try simulating different initiation measures (eg. one atom, multiple atoms, gaussian, uniform over interval, triangle over interval, etc.) and analyze how they influence $\mathbb{E}t_D(x)$ to come up with some heuristics for the optimization problem "find $f(x)$ that best explains observed $\mathbb{E}t_D(x)$"

Answer (score 1):

I provide some literature about modeling .

[image: lambertW]

See the reference 2. for the picture

Reference :

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.4554v5
2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X17305218
3. https://d-nb.info/993110037/34

For a physical interpretation see [wave pendulum](https://youtu.be/2qrBPFx-vQ8?si=KqVAlkckpVMbapBK) with same length and on the same line at $t=0$ .

Well it's not wave pendulum it's Newton's pendulum [image: n]

Remark : we can follow a very different way with Laplacian operator and Feynman-Kac formula see [Solving a PDE with Feynman-Kac Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064716/solving-a-pde-with-feynman-kac-formula)

Comment: Lambert W functions are exciting! Can you expand more on how to relate them to my problem? I initially thought of using an inverse Laplace transform, but that does not seem to lead anywhere. Any further ideas?

Comment: @samwolfe The paper is a bit hard for me but this one is understandable and provide a lower bound https://userweb.ucs.louisiana.edu/~xxw6637/papers/ASY2014.pdf . It use the Grönwall  lemma and use Lambert W