# How to simplify $\int_0^t \int_{x-s}^{x+s}\sum_i \delta(y-i)f(i,s)\,dyds$?

Tags: integration, summation, dirac-delta

Consider the following double integral
$$
\int_0^t \int_{x-s}^{x+s}\sum_i \delta(y-i)f(i,s)\,dyds
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function and $x,i\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there a way to simplify this?

**My attempt:** Using the properties of the Dirac delta, we get
$$
\int_0^t \sum_{i=\lceil x-s\rceil}^{\lfloor x+s \rfloor} f(i,s)\,ds
$$
since $x\pm s$ are not necessarily integers. I feel there is not much else I can do, but I might be missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac Delta is ***not*** a function.  And the linear functionals are **not** integrals.  In fact, the product of Heaviside function and the Dirac Delta is not defined.

If we were to proceed heuristically, we might write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{x-s}^{x+s}\delta(y-i)\,dyf(i,s)\,dy&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(H(y-x-s)-H(y-x+s)\right)\delta(y-i)\,dy\\\\
&=H(i-x-s)-H(i-x+s)
\end{align}$$

Then, we would have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^t \int_{x-s}^{x+s}\sum_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}\delta(y-i)\,dy\,f(i,s)\,ds&=\int_0^t \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sum_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}\left(H(y-x-s)-H(y-x+s)\right)\delta(y-i)\,dy\,f(i,s)\,ds\\\\
&=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_0^t \left(H(i-x-s)-H(i-x+s)\right)\,f(i,s)\,ds
\end{align}$$

And you can finish now.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.