# Generalizing a Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-function, integral-transforms

Consider the function given by
$$
F(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\int_0^t\int_{x-vs}^{x+vs}f(y)\,dyds} \,dt
$$
Is it possible to invert this and write $f$ in terms of $F$?

**Some thoughts:** If $F$ was in the form
$$
F(x)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-xt} \,dt
$$
I could potentially use the [inverse of a Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Inverse_Laplace_transform). If, for example, $f(x)=x$, we get
$$
F(x)=\frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{xv}}
$$
but the general case might not be invertible. Any ideas?